# Boost deadline timer fires continuously after IO service restart

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working on some comms code for which I need a regular timer for monitoring. I'm using boost ASIO for the comms so I decided to use a deadline timer for the timing and put it on the same IO service.

Everything works great the first time the code is run but it goes wrong once the comms (in my case a serial port) is stopped and restarted. The timer begins to malfunction and the comms break down. I believe the two are related so I'm just focusing on the timer for this question.

Consider the code below. This should start a timer and let it run for 10 seconds, stop the timer, and then start it again for another 10 seconds. What actually happens though is that when the timer is restarted it fires continuously, ie without any delay between firing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime timer_start_;

void CallbackTimerFunc(boost::asio::deadline_timer* timer) {
  auto time_since_start = timer->expires_at() - timer_start_;
  std::cout << "It's been " << time_since_start.total_seconds() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  // Sleep is here to prevent spamming when timer starts malfunctioning.
  usleep(20000);

  timer->expires_at(timer->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&CallbackTimerFunc, timer));
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*args*/) {
  // Start
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline_timer_(io_service_);
  deadline_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer_start_ = deadline_timer_.expires_at();
  deadline_timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&CallbackTimerFunc, &deadline_timer_));
  std::thread io_thread_(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));

  // Stop
  sleep(10);
  io_service_.stop();
  while (!io_service_.stopped()) usleep(10000);
  deadline_timer_.cancel();
  io_thread_.join();

  std::cout << "******************************" << std::endl;

  // Restart
  io_service_.restart();
  deadline_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer_start_ = deadline_timer_.expires_at();
  deadline_timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&CallbackTimerFunc, &deadline_timer_));
  io_thread_ = std::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));

  // Stop
  sleep(10);
  io_service_.stop();
  while (!io_service_.stopped()) usleep(10000);
  deadline_timer_.cancel();
  io_thread_.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Expected output is for the timer to count to 10 (well in reality from 0 to 8) twice. The actual output is that it counts to 10 once, and then just goes haywire claiming that hundreds of seconds are passing.

I can make this code work by creating a brand new IO service and timer but that seems like it should be unnecessary given that they are supposed to be reusable.

If anyone can tell me what's going on here or at least reproduce my results I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the error code.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently trying to figure out why I'm unable to pass that with boost::bind even though example code I'm reading online is doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tkausl for putting me on the right track. Here is the corrected code. Note the extra check at the top of `CallbackTimerFunc`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime timer_start_;

void CallbackTimerFunc(const boost::system::error_code& error, boost::asio::deadline_timer* timer) {
  if (error.value() == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
    std::cout << "Abort was sent on the first firing. Because of course it would be. Ignoring it will fix the problem. Because of course it will." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  auto time_since_start = timer->expires_at() - timer_start_;
  std::cout << "It's been " << time_since_start.total_seconds() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  // Sleep is here to prevent spamming when timer starts malfunctioning.
  usleep(20000);

  timer->expires_at(timer->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&CallbackTimerFunc, boost::asio::placeholders::error, timer));
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*args*/) {
  // Start
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline_timer_(io_service_);
  deadline_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer_start_ = deadline_timer_.expires_at();
  deadline_timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(CallbackTimerFunc, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &deadline_timer_));
  std::thread io_thread_(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));

  // Stop
  sleep(10);
  io_service_.stop();
  while (!io_service_.stopped()) usleep(10000);
  deadline_timer_.cancel();
  io_thread_.join();

  std::cout << "******************************" << std::endl;

  // Restart
  io_service_.restart();
  deadline_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
  timer_start_ = deadline_timer_.expires_at();
  deadline_timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(CallbackTimerFunc, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &deadline_timer_));
  io_thread_ = std::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));

  // Stop
  sleep(10);
  io_service_.stop();
  while (!io_service_.stopped()) usleep(10000);
  deadline_timer_.cancel();
  io_thread_.join();

  return 0;
}
```